# How to resolve symbols after statically linking to Visual C++ Runtime?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, libjpeg

I have a little command line project which makes use of the jpeglib from the [jpeg group](http://www.ijg.org/) and I want to statically link to the VC++ Runtime so I can distribute my executable more easily.

I found numerous posts explaining that you have to set:

**Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library**

to `/MT`

But this gives me several unresolved symbols.

47 Errors in Debug mode
5 Errors in Release mode

```
1>jpeg.lib(jdatasrc.obj) : error LNK2001: Unresolved External Symbol "__imp__fread".
1>jpeg.lib(jdatadst.obj) : error LNK2001: Unresolved External Symbol "__imp__ferror".
1>jpeg.lib(jmemmgr.obj) : error LNK2001: Unresolved External Symbol "__imp____stdio_common_vsscanf".
1>jpeg.lib(jdmarker.obj) : error LNK2001: Unresolved External Symbol "__imp__strncpy".
1>MSVCRT.lib(_chandler4gs_.obj) : error LNK2001: Unresolved External Symbol "__except_handler4_common".
```

I dont know what to do. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: The jpeg.lib you use was built with /MD, mixing is not possible.  You'll have to rebuild it.

Comment: @HansPassant The errors went away, I'll have to test it. If this works, you made me a very happy person. Thank you!